Embedding a codepen in a (MDSVEX) markdown page in Sveltekit
I have a site that uses Sveltekit and MDSVEX to convert markdown documents (+page.md) into web pages and embed them in a section's template. In my "Lab" section, I list all of my experiments via frontmatter in the markdown docs and when a user goes to the experiment page, I would like to show a codepen. I have tried both HTML and iFrame embeds in the markdown. This generally renders nothing but a border and the problem (at least with HTML embed appears to be the <script async> call that the embed requires. I have also tried to include both in a component (CodePen.svelte) and include that in the markdown file as you would typically include a component in a markdown file (with a <script> import Component... line and then the component <CodePen> in the body somewhere. Neither of these methods work either. Is there a technique that I am missing or is this just not possible?

What does the <iframe> code you use look like? Do you get it by asking CodePen to generate that code for you? How do you try to use it in your Markdown file? Do you get any loading error in the console that can suggest why it isn't loaded?

This is highly curious. I am sure that I tried embedding the codependent with an iframe in the .md file. But when I tried again this morning, it worked! Problem solved, I guess.

So, it turns out that you can include iframe content in a MDSVEX +page.md file. It is as simple as including the HTML directly in the file like so:
title: Keypress Description
date: '2023-02-10'
summary: 'Examining what keypress events produce'
experimentImage: '/images/lab/keypress-description.png'
experimentUrl: 'lab/keypress-description'
---

## Experiment: Capturing Keypress Events

<div class="experiment">
<iframe height="600" style="width: 100%;" scrolling="no" title="Keypress Description" src="https://codepen.io/russellbits/embed/XWqXPNG?default-tab=html%2Cresult" frameborder="no" loading="lazy" allowtransparency="true" allowfullscreen="true">
  See the Pen <a href="https://codepen.io/russellbits/pen/XWqXPNG">
  Keypress Description</a> by Russell Warner (<a href="https://codepen.io/russellbits">@russellbits</a>)
  on <a href="https://codepen.io">CodePen</a>.
</iframe>
</div>

<style>
.experiment {
    margin: 2em 0 0 0;
}
</style>```

